# ASP.NET C# Only allow bool set to true in 1 column of a table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am just trying to both understand how I can achieve this logically and what I would need to write in my code.

I have an application that allows me to send off user applications to Driving instructors and the instructor will update the application with either accept or reject. If the user has been accepted, the user can then choose to accept the offer by updating the application and selecting the firm tickbox. I only want it so that each user can only have one firm application and any other attempts at selecting a firm application will fail as the user should only be able to have 1 firm.

The code below is just a version that will look for any firm choice being set to true and throwing an error to the user taking them back to the application form. It works up to not allowing any firm choice to be made but obviously I need to be able to select only 1. I just can't work out how to check if only 1 firm choice has been made already by the user.

There are 2 models being used, Application - which acts as the context class holding the table data, this has the field Firm of type bool. The other model is the class for updating the application - ApplicationEdit which also holds the field Firm of type bool.

If I need to upload anything else, please let me know!

```
    public ActionResult UpdateApplication(int ApplicationId)
    {
        ApplicationEdit applicationEdit = new ApplicationEdit();
        Application application = applicationService.GetApplication(ApplicationId);
        applicationEdit.ApplicationId = application.ApplicationId;
        applicationEdit.Level= application.Level;
        applicationEdit.InstructorName = application.InstructorName;
        applicationEdit.InstructorNumber = application.InstructorNumber;
        applicationEdit.Firm = application.Firm;
        applicationEdit.Accepted = application.Accepted;
        return View(applicationEdit);
    }

        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateApplication(int ApplicationId, ApplicationEdit applicationEdit)
    {
        if(applicationEdit.Firm == false)
        try
        {
            applicationService.UpdateApplication(applicationEdit, ApplicationId);
            return RedirectToAction("GetUser", "User", new { ApplicationId = applicationEdit.ApplicationId });
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('Sorry, You can only have 1 firm choice, please update the old application and untick firm option there.')</script>");
            return View();//       return View();  return RedirectToAction("UpdateApplication", new { ApplicationId = applicationEdit.ApplicationId });
        }
    }
```

Application Database Definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Applications] (
[ApplicationId] INT IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Level] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[InstructorName] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[InstructorNumber] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[Firm] BIT NOT NULL,
[Instructor_InstructorId] INT NULL,
[User_UserId] NVARCHAR (128) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Applications] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ApplicationId] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Applications_dbo.Instructors_Instructor_InstructorId] FOREIGN KEY ([Instructor_InstructorId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Instructors] ([InstructorId]),
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Applications_dbo.Users_User_UserId] FOREIGN KEY ([User_UserId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Users] ([UserId])
```

);

Comment: Hello there. seems like you need validation on 2 parts. Client side validation on your page via javascript. You can process checkbox/CB clicks, handle process there on. prevent clicked CB from being "checked" if there is already a firm with a "checked" CB etc. Second part is on the backend , function of which you already posted.In this you're checking "firm" variable inside ApplicationEdit  object. Variable name seems a bit confusing. Better to give a more  clear name. Also title mentions a column of a table but I can't see any table structure. Can you elaborate more about this?

Comment: @AntiqTech Why would I need 2 part validation? Surely the validation can be checked purely in the backend by looking if any record in the table has the bool set to true? I am extremely inexperienced in the JS so writing validation there will be an issue, I would've thought the backend would just redirect the user to the application form once failed so you can check the box but once you submit it wont commit the change in the database. The reasoning for Firm is somewhat similiar as to what you'd have with University applications. I have uploaded the table definition if you want to have a look.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying. You don't need both of them. But it's better to do both. Cover all your bases. What kind of data will be coming from the frontend when multiple firms are checked ?  Also regarding database; "Only allow bool set to true in 1 column of a table"; Do you mean you don't want any records with firm=false? if so , maybe you can change this column name to firm_id and set "not null" in the definition. So any record without a firm_id [int] (firm connection) would be rejected by db directly (covering your bases), also on backend, check for firm_id, reject ones without it.

Comment: Also it would be better to provide us with the front end code to give a broader perspective.